# UPDATE after an INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have the following tables:

Table1:

```
id   name    race_type        start_time              end_time
---  ----    ---------        ----------              --------
111  Phelps   Relay       2016-08-20 00:01:00           NULL
111  Phelps   Relay             NULL             2016-08-20 00:02:00
333  Lochte  Butterfly    2016-08-20 00:05:00           NULL
333  Lochte  Butterfly          NULL             2016-08-20 00:06:00
```

Table2:

```
name      race_type        current_time       qualifies
----      ---------        ------------       ---------
Phelps      Relay       2016-08-20 00:03:30    
Lochte    Butterfly     2016-08-20 00:05:30
```

I use the following query to determine if the CURRENT_TIME for the two transaction in Table2, falls within the START_TIME and END_TIME of Table1 records with respect to each unique ID pairing, name, and race_type.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT id,name,race_type, MIN(start_time) AS start_time, MAX(end_time) AS end_time
FROM Table1
GROUP BY id
) AS results INNER JOIN table2 ON 
  results.name = Table2.name 
  AND results.type = Table2.type 
  AND Table2.current_time BETWEEN results.start_time AND results.end_time;
```

How would I modify this query to UPDATE the Table2.qualifies parameter to either true or false based on whether there were results returned or not for the two transactions in Table2

Table2 should look like this after the modification:

```
name      race_type        current_time       qualifies
----      ---------        ------------       ---------
Phelps      Relay       2016-08-20 00:03:30       0    
Lochte    Butterfly     2016-08-20 00:05:30       1
```

I'm guessing I need to add an UPDATE along with exists somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting/updating records programmatically, You should modify your Database structure and do it this way:

**Table 1:**

```
id   name    race_type     start_time           end_time   current_time   qualifies
---  ----    ---------     ----------           --------    ----------      ----
111  Phelps   Relay       2016-08-20 00:01:00     NULL        NULL          null
```

The above will be starting point (while inserting record first time)

Then once you get `current time` value in  your code, fire an update query and update the value of this record's (id 111) current_time column.

Then fire a select query with `WHERE` and `BETWEEN` clause and according to your conditions, update qualifies column value as well.

NOTE: I posted this as answer because of character limits in comment section. So please dont downvote. Also, this answer shows correct and better way to structure database as well.

Comment: Modifying the database is not an option. Some of advice to help  answer the original question would have been nice, instead of filling up valuable answer space.

Comment: @sumitbadaya It does look like the question has been answered - which is a little unfortunate from the point of view of the OP

Comment: Yes the question has been answered but @user3567212 is blind enough to see it and opts to code in a very poor way. Well I pity on the project that's under his hand. lol